# adding rows based on a field value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA scripting and still trying to find my way. Is it possible to work with an array and add the number of rows through a field? So in this case it's 28. If I type in 12, it should adapt to show 12 rows, including lines.

Does anyone has example code to share?

[image: screen 1]
[image: screen 2]

Comment: I'm not clear on the question. Are you asking to insert new formatting below your current table or hiding what already exists? If it's the latter, I feel like you could save yourself a lot of work by using the filter functionality built into Excel.

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried? Have a go at recording what you do to give you a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim udLoop As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' user defined loop
    udLoop = ws.Cells(1, 6) + 1

    ' clear existing data
    ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(31, 3)).Clear

    ' maximum value validation
    If udLoop > 31 Then
        MsgBox "Days cannot exceed 31." & vbNewLine & "Macro has been halted."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To udLoop
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = i - 1
        'ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = 'add result value here
        ' percentage of the total results for row i
        ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = Format(ws.Cells(i, 2).Value / Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lRow, 2))), "0%")
    Next i

    ' find last row
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' format new table
    With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, 3))
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give it a try!

Comment: Let me know how you make out.